# getmap fails at getmapdl

Tags: miktex, getmap

I'm using MikTex 2.9, TexStudio 2.11.0 and the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[overwrite=true,mode=gm]{getmap}
\begin{document}
\getmap[mode=gm,xsize=500,ysize=500,scale=2,zoom=3]{Berlin}
\end{document}
```

Fails with the following output:

```
Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 "TKD Map".tex

Der Befehl "getmapdl" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Prozess endete normal
```

Could anyone please tell me why getmap is not working?
I tried crawling behind this but was not able to find out what went wrong.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably your distribution is unable to execute the `getmapdl` program. Is it in `PATH`? Probably you want to test that.

Comment: what means getmapdl is in path?

Comment: es konntenkeine dateien mit dem angegebenen muster gefunden werden...ich nehme an es fehlt, habe nirgendwo gelesen, dass ich das brauche. wo bekomme ich das denn?

Comment: How did you install the getmap package?

Comment: using the miktex package manager. am i right in assuming that texlive is missing?

Comment: No. Your example works fine in miktex (it doesn't output anything as you are not using the graphic, but doesn't give errors).  Do you have a multiuser miktex?

Comment: how do i find that out? i tried texworks, same result :-(

Comment: Do you have two package managers? One with "admin"?

Comment: yes, i used the admin one, actually both show getmap as installed

Comment: Hm. Deinstall it in both package manager and then try if it works if you install it again with the package manager admin.

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't help, niether in texworks nor in texstudio. tex live is installing which includes texlive-pictures, containing getmapdl...

Comment: The editor doesn't matter. And you naturally can switch to texlive. But it would be good to know why the wrapper isn't there or isn't found. Do you have a getmapdl.exe in the miktex/bin folder beside pdflatex?

Comment: there is not getmapdl.exe file in the folder. Should it come there with the package?

Comment: It should be created at the installation, it is a small wrapper. Is your system up-to-date? Try `initexmf --admin --mklinks` in a command line with admin rights.

Comment: i did that, but nothing visible happened and nonetheless the file is not there. is it possible to manually put it there?

Comment: No you can't do it manually. In miktex/config there is a scripts.ini. Which date has it and does it contain a line for getmapdl? Don't change the file!!  (And add @UlrikeFischer to your comments, so that I get notified).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the date is 2013/12/23, there is no line for it. After 2.5 h, the texlive installation now is finished and there it is running with write18 enabled. So it looks like for some reason my miktex version can't run getmap?

Comment: Your miktex (at least some core files) are really outdated. You probably could write yourself a batch-file which calls the luascript, but if your other executable (e.g. luatex) are also so old then I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: okay, thank you very much. my system is pretty new, so i dont understand that. nonetheless we found the bug and with the newer texlive it works now. thank you :-) @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 1):

i) It would be useful to insert the getmap in the MWE with `\includegraphics` 
ii) In Google gm or gsv mode it does nothing for me, in no (manual) example. There's something in the manual about request restrictions, maybe it has something to do with it. 
iii) Otherwise I run the process with arara.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell : yes }
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[overwrite=true,
%mode=gm
]{getmap}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Map of Berlin}
\getmap[mode=osm,
xsize=500,ysize=500,
%scale=500,
zoom=10
]{Berlin}
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{getmap}
\end{document}
```